# LED strip PWM on GPIO18 + mono audio output

Tags: gpio, audio, led, pwm, alsa

On the RPi 3 I would like to control a WS2811 LED strip with PWM (GPIO18) by keeping the audio working.

It looks like for the RPi Zero (I'm unsure for RPI 3 though) left and right channels of the built-in 3.5mm jack are hooked up to GPIO13 and GPIO18.

Is it possible to downmix audio to 1 channel so that we can use the audio jack in mono mode and keep GPIO18 free for the LED strip?

I've been trying the `.asoundrc` configuration below without success. It actually redirects L+R to L very well, but still conflicts with the LED strip:

```
pcm.monocard {
  slave.pcm card0
  slave.channels 2
  type route
  ttable {
    0.0 1
    1.0 1
    0.1 0
    1.1 0
  }
}
```

Comment: That configuration just outputs zero-valued samples on the right channel. I guess you have to re[configure the GPIO pin](http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples) itself.

Comment: @CL. Is [this tuto](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md) the right way to do this? What is the goal in the end, disabling GPIO 18 as audio, forcing PWM on GPIO 18, ...?